# How To Make Featured Image/Post Thumbnail to be the background image of a DIV?

Tags: php

So I have this code:

```
<?php $background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'full' ); ?>

<div  class="imgholder" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $background[0]; ?>');">
```

The first line (php) is to get and enable the featured image/Post Thumbnail to be the **background image** of my specified div container.

The second line is the div container with a css style of background that assigns the featured image/Post Thumbnail.

To summarize, the code works like it will make the featured image/Post Thumbnail (**in its** **default size**) as a background image.

The codes works like a charm, hands down to the person who coded that!

My situation, I want to modify this a that will fit to my needs.

I have a function below which is tasked to crop and resize the image.

```
add_theme_support('TypeOneImage');
set_post_thumbnail_size( 726, 525, true );
add_image_size( 'TypeTwo', 726, 525, true );
```

My problem is, how can I integrate the two codes into one.

What I'm trying to achieve here is to make the featured image/Post Thumbnail attachment 'TypeOneImage' to be the background of my div?

Why I don't like the first code above? It's because the first code generates the default or original size of the image. I need something smaller and cropped. I'm after the smaller size which i believe affects the site's speed.

Hope someone could help.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php $background = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $page->ID ), 'TypeTwo' ); ?>

<div  class="imgholder" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $background[0]; ?>');">
```

I assume TypeTwo or 726 X 525is the size you want . 
If you looking for smaller size . either you change your function values to
add_image_size( 'TypeTwo',640,560, true ); 
or add new one called

```
add_image_size( 'PostBg',640,560, true );
```

Last don't forget to Use [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin to regenerate all your post Thumbnails

Answer (score -1):

The later code, including the size attributes needs to be pasted in your theme's `functions.php` file, with the `after_setup_theme` hook.

For example-

```
function theme_setup(){
add_theme_support('TypeOneImage');
set_post_thumbnail_size( 726, 525, true );
add_image_size( 'TypeTwo', 726, 525, true );
}
add_action('after_setup_theme','theme_setup');
```

After this deactivate your theme, and reactivate it. Now, whenever you query an image of 'TypeTwo' size, you would get an image of 726x525 (due to `add_image_size( 'TypeTwo', 726, 525, true )`), and a query to the Featured Image would also return 726x525 (due to `set_post_thumbnail_size( 726, 525, true )`).